# A crazy number theoretic problem

Tags: number-theory

How many positive integers satisfy the condition that the product of their digits multiplied by the sum of their digits equals themselves? For example,

13 is not equal to (1+3)(1×3)

Here is how i proceeded
I defined a number n such that $10^{k+1}$$>$$n$$>$$10^k$
Next, i will expand the number in powers of tens.
Now i am trying to create a bound, but at this stage, i am unsuccessful in each of my attempts. Please help me!

Comment: Did you search the site this time before posting?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I  mean, whether your question is new here or already has answers, i.e., is a duplicate?

Comment: No i have not searcehed

Comment: You should always do this to avoid duplicates (which you have for several of your questions already).

Comment: I am actually new so i dont know much i joined only 2 days before

Comment: But i assume this question will not have any such duplicates

Comment: A $k$-digit solution $n$ would satisfy $10^{k-1}\le n\le k9^{k+1}$ so $90k\ge (10/9)^k$ and (by a computer search) $k\le 84$. So it may be hard to find all solutions by brute force.

Comment: Yes that is the problem now

Comment: There's actually a name for this sort of number! Let $n$ be a number such that

$$n = \text{(product of n's digits)} \times \text{(sum of n's digits)}$$

Then $n$ is what we call a "sum-product number." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum-product_number) In base $10$, there are only four such numbers, only two of which are nontrivial - 135 and 144. It has been proven that the number of such numbers in any given base is also finite.

The Wikipedia article linked will be a good starting point for looking into this topic. I don't know much offhand about proving stuff of this sort though.

Comment: *"But i assume this question will not have any such duplicates"* No. As a rule of thumb, every idea you have is unoriginal.

Comment: @J.G.:  you can reduce the search a lot by thinking about factorization.  I sketch it in my edit.  I think the search space is down to tens or hundreds of millions, which is easily doable.

Answer (score 1):

To set an upper bound, note that each digit is at most $9$.  If the number has $n$ digits, the computation gives at most $(9n)(9^n)=n9^{n+1}$.  An $n$ digit number is at least $10^{n-1}$.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n*9%5E(n%2B1)%3D10%5E(n-1)) tells us that for $n=85$ we have the number is greater than the sum of digits times the product of digits, so you only have to search up to $10^{84}$.  Happy hunting.

Now note that most of the factors of the number need to be $2,3,5,7$ because the only way you can get a larger one is from the sum of the digits.  As lulu points out you can't have both $2$ and $5$ as factors because it would end in zero and the product would be zero.  The number needs to be $2^a3^b7^cd$ or $3^a5^b7^cd$ with $d \lt 9\cdot 84$.  If you have a programming language that supports large ints, like Python, and a nice way to turn a number into a string you can just do the search.  A little cleverness can speed it up, like noting that $e$ can't be that large unless the other numbers are large.

Comment: So whats next? You just created the bound, but this is just a mere observation

Comment: @Md.ShamimAkhtar You could give it some thought yourself. You might learn something from it.

Comment: A bound is what you asked for.

Comment: Note: saves time to note that your number can't be divisible by both $2$ and $5$ (else it would end in $0$ and the product of its digits would be $0$).

Comment: @lulu:  good point.  That reduces the search space considerably.  I saw that they only used $2,3,7$ and $3,4,5$ in the Wikipedia article after I wrote this but didn't think about it.

Comment: Yes approach is good, but what if such problem coomes in any contests?

Comment: I don't think this is a reasonable contest problem unless you can reduce the search space much more.  I don't know how and the Wikipedia article only cites the same upper limit I found.